# Website accessibility rundown - rules, things to do, tips, etc

Tags: accessibility

Accessibility is important to me as I'm a physically disabled developer.  I'd like to make sure I have a good feel for what it takes to make a site accessible while also being pointed in the right direction for the things I'm uncertain with, or just haven't considered.  So, here's what I'm comfortable with right now:

Alt text for images with meaning.

Percentage or font-relative measurements (ems) for those who need to re-size their screens.

Colors with good contrast for those with colorblindness.

Textual representation of any audio/visual material.

**Questions:**

Should I make a link at the top of the site to jump down to content on every page?

How is JavaScript handled by screen readers?

Is there anything major I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WebAim.org](http://webaim.org/) is a great resource for all things web-accessibly related. Suggest starting off with their [WCAG (Web Content Accessibility Guidelines) checklist](http://webaim.org/standards/wcag/checklist).

Quick answers to your qu's:

> Should I make a link at the top of the site to jump down to content on every page?

This is currently recommended best practice. (Eventually HTML5 semantic tags will remove the need for this, but we're not there yet. One thing to watch for: if you do use a hidden link, be sure to make it visible again when it has focus, so that sighted keyboard users don't get 'lost'.)

> How is JavaScript handled by screen readers?

All depends on what you use it for. The main area for problem is if new content appears that the user is supposed to be aware of (eg. popups, expanding blocks); if it doesn't get keyboard focus, a screenreader may not read it out to the user and the user may not realize that anything has changed. This is one area where it may be necessary to test with a real-world screenreader (eg. NVDA or JAWS) to ensure that it's actually usable. A simple approach is to only have UI appear in response to user request: eg user hits return on a menu item to make the menu appear, don't make it appear merely in response to it getting focus. Then when it does appear, set focus to the first item: this is both expected behavior for menus in most UIs, and changing the focus typically also causes the screenreader to read out the new item, which confirms to the user that something has happened. (Also, if using Javascript to add behavior to existing elements - eg. make a link behave like a button - use [WAI-ARIA](http://webaim.org/techniques/aria/) attributes such as role="button" to let the screenreader know what the intent is so it will read out that role to the user, and will say 'button' instead of 'link'.)

> Is there anything major I'm missing?

I think you've got most of the key points already covered above; the WCAG checklist should fill in everything else. One major area that is worth mentioning is to use headers (H1, etc) appropriately. For screenreader users, navigating by header is a major way for navigating a page. Typically when navigating to a page that a user hasn't visited before, the user will hit a hot-key to get the screenreader to bring up a list of headings on that page as a way of 'skimming' to get an overview. Having good link text is also important; ideally links should be self-describing, so you don't just hear "click for more", "click for more" as you tab through a page.

Comment: As a blind programmer who uses a screen reader on a daily basis I'd just like to say you have provided good info.

Answer (score 1):

For newer browsers, IE8, IE9, Firefox 3?, and Safari 5 (possibly 4), and newer screen readers [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/) is the way to go. Among other things it has landmark roles which if you have an ARIA reading screen reader, such as JAWS 12 and possibly JAWS 11 and 10, the screen reader can use to jump around. It can get a bit clunky if you want things to be backwards accessible but is the direction the web is going in. Their are many other advantages to ARIA but that's the one relevant to your question. On a related note VoiceOver for the Mac is supposed to be ARIA compliant as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not disagreeing with the selected best answer, but I would spend more time learning about WCAG 2.0 than with the original WCAG specification. Both in the United States and internationally, the Web Content Accessibility Guideline 2.0 are quickly becoming the standard. In fact, the Access Board, the group tasked with defining the guidelines for Section 508, are refreshing the standards to be harmonized with WCAG 2.0.

You can find great information by starting here [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/).